# unable to access web application in iis

Tags: iis, localhost

I would like to ask suggestion regarding the current issue that i have. I have a visual studio project and it only runs on **IIS Express**

I have done the ff:

- set the project url to : http://localhost/test.Global/
- i have clicked the **"Create Virtual Directory**"
- I have give full control on the permission for IUSR and IIS_IUSR

  i can access this url only when visual studio project is running.

what i wanted to achieve is to make http://localhost/test.Global accessible without running the visual studio.

this is the error that i have:

[image]

Comment: "what i wanted to achieve is to make http://localhost/test.Global accessible without running the visual studio" is impossible. Only when you run a project in VS, IIS Express will be launched and monitor that URL.

Comment: you a have point there but then when i set the server to Local IIS it won't proceed and it gaves me an error of "Unable to start debugging on the web server. Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: The local IIS issue is well known, so you should search existing threads to see how to resolve it. Windows HTTP API is so fragile that anything can break VS debugging on IIS or IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

You can run IIS Express outside of Visual Studio by starting a command prompt and entering something like:

```
iisexpress /path:c:\myapp\
```

This will run an application in the specified folder on port 8080 (http://localhost:8080/).

Full details are in the [Microsoft documentation](http://You%20can%20run%20IIS%20Express%20outside%20of%20Visual%20Studio%20by%20starting%20a%20command%20prompt%20and%20entering%20something%20like:%20%20%20%20%20%20iisexpress%20/path:c:%5Cmyapp%5C%20%20This%20will%20run%20an%20application%20in%20the%20specified%20folder%20on%20port%208080%20(http://localhost:8080/).%20%20Full%20details%20are%20in%20the%20[Microsoft%20documentation][1].).

Answer (score 0):

kindly please close this thread as i have resolved the issue by unistalling the IIS and reinstalling it.

Comment: if your issue resolved I request you to mark the suggestion as an answer. it will help other people who face a similar issues.